# Div sections appearing under page div

Tags: html

I've just started coding my own websites and have run into a bit of a problem. I have made a 'page' div that is 960px wide and want to include 2 sections within it side by side, but when I try, they appear under the 'page' div. What can I do to have them within the page?

```css
#page { 
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 720px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-color: #b7fd9b;
    border: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;  
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;  
    background-clip: padding-box; 
 }
  
 #sectionleft {
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#sectionright {
    font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    
<head>
<title>Very Vegetarian</title>
<link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    
<div id="page">

    <h1>Welcome!</h1>

    <div id="sectionleft">
        <p>This website is for teenagers that have thought about the idea of vegetarianism and want to learn more about it. It includes easy vegetarian recipes that are very simple to make yet really tasty to eat, with ingredients that can be found in any common kitchen cupboard. There is a page with some information about what vegetarianism really is and the benefits of becoming a vegetarian, and another page with useful links to other websites if your interest has been peaked by this website. </p>
    </div>

    <div id="sectionright">
    &ldquo;Nothing will benefit human health and increase the chances for survival of life on Earth as much as the evolution to a vegetarian diet.&rdquo; <br>
    - Albert Einstein
    </div>
  
</div>    

</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: It's Albert Einstein, not "Einstien". Had to say it.

Answer (score 0):

The "page" element basically only contains the h1 element, in terms of contents, while the rest of the content is under the left and right div.
This causes your text to "clip" out of the main container, a simple solution is to set an overflow value to your page:

```
#page { 
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 720px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-color: #b7fd9b;
    border: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;  
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;  
    background-clip: padding-box; 
}
```

By setting your overflow to "hidden" you are forcing your div to cover all the space of your child elements, hiding this "clipping", check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp for more info.